# How to extract a specific cell in Rstudio?

Tags: r

I am currently working with a data table called "beta" which I made from a CSV file. I can't seem to find a way to extract a specific row from my data table "beta" to use in creating a beta function histogram.

As far as I know the functions

```
beta$a
beta$b
```

would extract the entirety of columns a and b from the data table. However, I only want it to extract the first row.

My overall code is

```
SampleValues <- rbeta(10,000, beta$a, beta$b)

SamplesHistogram <- ggplot(beta, aes(SampleValues))

dput(head(beta))
```

Which gives me the error

```
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (33): x
```

That's why I am trying to make my Aesthetics only 1 row

Here's my table if needed

```
structure(list(weld.type.ID = 1:6, weld.type = structure(c(273L, 
63L, 116L, 27L, 268L, 121L), .Label = c("1,1/2\",Material A", 
"1,1/4\",Material A", "1,1/4\",Material C", "1,10,Material A", 
"1,10S,Material C", "1,120,Material A", "1,120,Material B", "1,120,Material C", 
"1,160,Material A", "1,160,Material B", "1,160,Material C", "1,160,Material D", 
"1,3/16\",Material A", "1,3/16\",Material C", "1,3000,Material A", 
"1,3000,Material C", "1,40,Material A", "1,40,Material B", "1,40,Material C", 
"1,40,Material D", "1,40S,Material A", "1,40S,Material C", "1,80,Material A", 
"1,80,Material B", "1,80,Material D", "1,80S,Material C", "1,STD,Material A", 
"1,STD,Material B", "1,STD,Material C", "1,Std.,Material A", 
"1,XS,Material A", "1,XS,Material B", "1,XS,Material C", "1,XS,Material D", 
"1,XXS,Material A", "1,XXS,Material B", "1,XXS,Material C", "10,1/4\",Material A", 
"10,1/4\",Material C", "10,10,Material A", "10,10,Material C", 
"10,10S,Material A", "10,10S,Material C", "10,120,Material A", 
"10,140,Material A", "10,160,Material A", "10,160,Material B", 
"10,160,Material C", "10,3/16\",Material A", "10,3/16\",Material C", 
"10,30,Material C", "10,3000,Material A", "10,40,Material A", 
"10,40,Material B", "10,40,Material C", "10,40,Material D", "10,40S,Material C", 
"10,5S,Material A", "10,80,Material A", "10,80,Material B", "10,80,Material D", 
"10,80S,Material C", "10,STD,Material A", "10,STD,Material B", 
"10,STD,Material C", "10,Std.,Material A", "10,XS,Material A", 
"10,XS,Material B", "10,XS,Material C", "10,XXS,Material A", 
"10,XXS,Material B", "10,XXS,Material C", "11,XS,Material A", 
"11,XXS,Material C", "12,1/4\",Material A", "12,100,Material A", 
"12,160,Material A", "12,STD,Material A", "12,XS,Material A", 
"13,1 1/4\",Material A", "13,1 1/4\",Material B", "13,1/4\",Material A", 
"13,1/4\",Material B", "13,1/4\",Material C", "13,1/8\",Material A", 
"13,10,Material C", "13,10S,Material A", "13,10S,Material C", 
"13,120,Material A", "13,120,Material B", "13,120,Material C", 
"13,160,Material A", "13,160,Material B", "13,160,Material C", 
"13,20,Material C", "13,3/16\",Material A", "13,3/8\",Material A", 
"13,3000,Material A", "13,40,Material A", "13,40,Material B", 
"13,40,Material C", "13,40,Material D", "13,40S,Material A", 
"13,40S,Material C", "13,40S,Material D", "13,5S,Material A", 
"13,60,Material A", "13,60,Material C", "13,6000,Material A", 
"13,80,Material A", "13,80,Material B", "13,80,Material D", "13,80S,Material A", 
"13,80S,Material C", "13,cl30,Material C", "13,STD,Material A", 
"13,STD,Material B", "13,STD,Material C", "13,STD,Material D", 
"13,Std.,Material A", "13,XS,Material A", "13,XS,Material B", 
"13,XS,Material C", "13,XXS,Material A", "13,XXS,Material B", 
"13,XXS,Material C", "14,1 1/4\",Material A", "14,1\",Material C", 
"14,1/2\",Material A", "14,1/4\",Material A", "14,1/4\",Material C", 
"14,1/8\",Material C", "14,10,Material A", "14,10,Material C", 
"14,100,Material A", "14,100,Material C", "14,10S,Material A", 
"14,10S,Material C", "14,120,Material A", "14,120,Material B", 
"14,120,Material C", "14,140,Material A", "14,160,Material A", 
"14,160,Material C", "14,20,Material C", "14,3/16\",Material A", 
"14,3/4\",Material C", "14,3/8\",Material A", "14,30,Material A", 
"14,3000,Material A", "14,40,Material A", "14,40,Material C", 
"14,40S,Material C", "14,60,Material A", "14,60,Material C", 
"14,6000,Material A", "14,80,Material A", "14,80,Material B", 
"14,80S,Material C", "14,cl80,Material A", "14,STD,Material A", 
"14,STD,Material B", "14,STD,Material C", "14,Std.,Material A", 
"14,XS,Material A", "14,XS,Material B", "14,XS,Material C", "14,XXS,Material A", 
"15,1 1/4\",Material A", "15,1 1/4\",Material C", "15,1/2\",Material A", 
"15,1/4\",Material A", "15,10,Material C", "15,100,Material A", 
"15,100,Material C", "15,10S,Material C", "15,120,Material A", 
"15,120,Material B", "15,120,Material C", "15,140,Material A", 
"15,140,Material B", "15,160,Material A", "15,160,Material C", 
"15,20,Material C", "15,3/8\",Material A", "15,30,Material A", 
"15,3000,Material A", "15,40,Material A", "15,40,Material C", 
"15,40S,Material A", "15,40S,Material C", "15,5S,Material A", 
"15,60,Material A", "15,60,Material B", "15,80,Material A", "15,80,Material B", 
"15,80,Material C", "15,80S,Material C", "15,80x1,Material A", 
"15,STD,Material A", "15,STD,Material B", "15,STD,Material C", 
"15,Std.,Material A", "15,XS,Material A", "15,XS,Material B", 
"15,XS,Material C", "15,XXS,Material A", "16,0.625\",Material A", 
"16,0.875\",Material A", "16,100,Material B", "16,100,Material C", 
"16,10S,Material C", "16,120,Material C", "16,140,Material A", 
"16,140,Material B", "16,140,Material C", "16,160,Material A", 
"16,20,Material A", "16,20,Material C", "16,3/8\",Material C", 
"16,30,Material A", "16,30,Material B", "16,40,Material A", "16,40S,Material C", 
"16,60,Material A", "16,60,Material B", "16,80,Material A", "16,80,Material B", 
"16,80,Material C", "16,80S,Material C", "16,STD,Material A", 
"16,STD,Material C", "16,XS,Material A", "16,XS,Material C", 
"18,1/4\",Material A", "19,3/16\",Material A", "2,1/4\",Material A", 
"2,1/4\",Material B", "2,10,Material A", "2,100,Material C", 
"2,10S,Material C", "2,120,Material A", "2,160,Material A", "2,160,Material B", 
"2,160,Material C", "2,160,Material D", "2,20,Material A", "2,3/16\",Material A", 
"2,3000,Material A", "2,3000,Material C", "2,40,Material A", 
"2,40,Material B", "2,40,Material C", "2,40,Material D", "2,40S,Material A", 
"2,40S,Material C", "2,60,Material A", "2,60,Material B", "2,6000,Material A", 
"2,80,Material A", "2,80,Material B", "2,80,Material C", "2,80,Material D", 
"2,80S,Material A", "2,80S,Material C", "2,cl30,Material A", 
"2,cl80,Material A", "2,STD,Material A", "2,STD,Material B", 
"2,STD,Material C", "2,STD,Material D", "2,Std.,Material A", 
"2,XS,Material A", "2,XS,Material B", "2,XS,Material C", "2,XS,Material D", 
"2,XXS,Material A", "2,XXS,Material B", "2,XXS,Material C", "20,1/4\",Material A", 
"20,160,Material A", "20,160,Material B", "20,40S,Material C", 
"20,STD,Material A", "20,XS,Material A", "20,XS,Material B", 
"21,120,Material B", "21,160,Material A", "21,160,Material B", 
"21,160,Material C", "21,160,Material D", "21,3000,Material A", 
"21,3000,Material C", "21,40,Material A", "21,40,Material C", 
"21,40S,Material C", "21,6000,Material A", "21,80,Material A", 
"21,80,Material B", "21,80S,Material C", "21,STD,Material A", 
"21,STD,Material C", "21,XS,Material A", "21,XS,Material B", 
"21,XS,Material C", "21,XXS,Material A", "21,XXS,Material B", 
"21,XXS,Material C", "21,XXS,Material D", "23,1/4\",Material A", 
"23,160,Material A", "23,160,Material B", "23,160,Material C", 
"23,160,Material D", "23,3/16\",Material A", "23,3000,Material A", 
"23,3000,Material B", "23,3000,Material C", "23,60,Material A", 
"23,6000,Material A", "23,80,Material A", "23,80,Material C", 
"23,80S,Material C", "23,9000,Material B", "23,STD,Material A", 
"23,XS,Material A", "23,XS,Material B", "23,XS,Material C", "23,XS,Material D", 
"23,XXS,Material A", "24,1/4\",Material A", "24,1/4\",Material C", 
"24,3/16\",Material A", "24,3/8\",Material D", "24,40,Material A", 
"24,40S,Material C", "24,80,Material A", "24,80,Material D", 
"24,STD,Material A", "24,XS,Material A", "25,0.625\",Material A", 
"25,0.875\",Material A", "25,1\",Material A", "25,1/2\",Material A", 
"25,1/2\",Material C", "25,1/4\",Material A", "25,20,Material A", 
"25,20,Material C", "25,30,Material A", "25,STD,Material A", 
"25,XS,Material A", "25,XS,Material B", "26,1 1/2\",Material B", 
"26,1\",Material C", "26,1/4\",Material A", "26,1/4\",Material C", 
"26,10,Material A", "26,100,Material B", "26,10S,Material C", 
"26,120,Material A", "26,120,Material C", "26,140,Material B", 
"26,160,Material A", "26,160,Material C", "26,20,Material A", 
"26,20,Material B", "26,20,Material C", "26,3/8\",Material C", 
"26,40,Material A", "26,40,Material B", "26,40,Material C", "26,40S,Material C", 
"26,60,Material A", "26,60,Material B", "26,60,Material C", "26,80,Material A", 
"26,80,Material B", "26,80,Material C", "26,80S,Material C", 
"26,STD,Material A", "26,STD,Material B", "26,STD,Material C", 
"26,STD,Material D", "26,XS,Material A", "26,XS,Material B", 
"27,STD,Material A", "27,XS,Material A", "28,0.625\",Material A", 
"28,0.688\",Material A", "28,0.875\",Material A", "28,1 1/4\",Material A", 
"28,1\",Material A", "28,1\",Material B", "28,1\",Material C", 
"28,1/4\",Material A", "28,10,Material C", "28,120,Material A", 
"28,20,Material A", "28,3/16\",Material A", "28,3/4\",Material A", 
"28,3/8\",Material A", "28,3/8\",Material C", "28,30,Material A", 
"28,40,Material A", "28,80,Material A", "28,80x1,Material A", 
"28,STD,Material A", "28,STD,Material C", "28,Std.,Material A", 
"28,XS,Material A", "28,XS,Material C", "29,0.625\",Material A", 
"29,1\",Material A", "29,1/2\",Material A", "29,1/2\",Material C", 
"29,1/4\",Material A", "29,20,Material A", "29,80,Material A", 
"29,STD,Material A", "29,XS,Material A", "29,XS,Material C", 
"31,0.625\",Material A", "31,0.688\",Material A", "31,STD,Material A", 
"32,1/2\",Material A", "33,3/16\",Material A", "33,STD,Material A", 
"33,XS,Material A", "35,STD,Material A", "35,STD,Material C", 
"37,STD,Material A", "38,1/4\",Material C", "38,3/16\",Material A", 
"4,1/4\",Material A", "4,10,Material A", "4,10,Material C", "4,100,Material A", 
"4,100,Material B", "4,100,Material C", "4,10S,Material C", "4,120,Material B", 
"4,140,Material A", "4,140,Material C", "4,160,Material A", "4,20,Material C", 
"4,3/8\",Material A", "4,30,Material A", "4,30,Material B", "4,3000,Material A", 
"4,40,Material A", "4,40,Material C", "4,40S,Material C", "4,60,Material A", 
"4,60,Material B", "4,60,Material C", "4,6000,Material A", "4,80,Material A", 
"4,80,Material B", "4,80,Material C", "4,80S,Material C", "4,STD,Material A", 
"4,STD,Material B", "4,STD,Material C", "4,XS,Material A", "4,XS,Material B", 
"4,XXS,Material A", "40,3/8\",Material D", "40,40,Material A", 
"40,STD,Material A", "41,STD,Material A", "41,STD,Material C", 
"41,XS,Material A", "41,XS,Material C", "42,XS,Material A", "44,0.625\",Material A", 
"44,10,Material B", "44,3/8\",Material C", "44,40S,Material C", 
"44,80,Material B", "44,STD,Material A", "44,STD,Material C", 
"44,XS,Material B", "47,1/4\",Material A", "47,1/4\",Material C", 
"47,10S,Material C", "47,3/16\",Material A", "47,80,Material A", 
"47,STD,Material A", "47,XS,Material A", "48,1/4\",Material A", 
"49,1/4\",Material A", "49,1/4\",Material C", "49,STD,Material A", 
"5,1/4\",Material A", "50,1/4\",Material A", "51,1/4\",Material A", 
"51,1/4\",Material C", "52,1/4\",Material C", "52,STD,Material A", 
"52,XS,Material A", "55,1/4\",Material A", "58,XS,Material A", 
"59,1/2\",Material C", "6,1 1/4\",Material A", "6,1\",Material A", 
"6,1/4\",Material A", "6,10,Material C", "6,100,Material A", 
"6,100,Material C", "6,10S,Material C", "6,120,Material A", "6,120,Material B", 
"6,140,Material A", "6,160,Material A", "6,160,Material C", "6,30,Material A", 
"6,3000,Material A", "6,40,Material A", "6,40,Material B", "6,40,Material C", 
"6,40S,Material C", "6,60,Material A", "6,60,Material B", "6,60,Material C", 
"6,6000,Material A", "6,80,Material A", "6,80,Material B", "6,80S,Material C", 
"6,STD,Material A", "6,STD,Material B", "6,STD,Material C", "6,STD,Material D", 
"6,Std.,Material A", "6,XS,Material A", "6,XS,Material B", "6,XS,Material C", 
"63,0.625\",Material A", "63,1/2\",Material B", "64,80S,Material C", 
"65,40,Material C", "65,STD,Material A", "66,10S,Material C", 
"66,STD,Material A", "66,STD,Material C", "67,20,Material A", 
"67,STD,Material A", "67,XS,Material A", "68,0.625\",Material A", 
"68,1/2\",Material A", "68,20,Material A", "68,STD,Material A", 
"7,0.875\",Material A", "7,1 1/4\",Material B", "7,1\",Material B", 
"7,1/4\",Material A", "7,1/4\",Material C", "7,100,Material B", 
"7,100,Material C", "7,140,Material A", "7,160,Material A", "7,20,Material C", 
"7,3/4\",Material A", "7,3/8\",Material A", "7,30,Material A", 
"7,30,Material B", "7,40,Material A", "7,40,Material C", "7,40S,Material A", 
"7,40S,Material C", "7,60,Material A", "7,80,Material A", "7,80,Material B", 
"7,80S,Material C", "7,cl30,Material B", "7,STD,Material A", 
"7,STD,Material B", "7,STD,Material C", "7,STD,Material D", "7,XS,Material A", 
"7,XS,Material B", "71,1/4\",Material C", "76,1/4\",Material C", 
"8,1/4\",Material A", "8,10,Material C", "8,10S,Material C", 
"8,160,Material A", "8,20,Material C", "8,3/8\",Material C", 
"8,30,Material A", "8,40,Material A", "8,40,Material C", "8,40S,Material A", 
"8,40S,Material C", "8,60,Material A", "8,80,Material A", "8,80,Material C", 
"8,80S,Material C", "8,STD,Material A", "8,STD,Material B", "8,STD,Material C", 
"8,XS,Material A", "8,XS,Material B", "8,XXS,Material A", "87,0.625\",Material A", 
"87,0.688\",Material A", "9,1\",Material A", "9,1/4\",Material A", 
"9,160,Material A", "9,160,Material B", "9,160,Material C", "9,160,Material D", 
"9,3000,Material A", "9,3000,Material B", "9,3000,Material C", 
"9,40,Material C", "9,40S,Material C", "9,6000,Material A", "9,6000,Material B", 
"9,80,Material A", "9,80,Material C", "9,80S,Material A", "9,80S,Material C", 
"9,9000,Material A", "9,STD,Material A", "9,STD,Material C", 
"9,XS,Material A", "9,XS,Material B", "9,XS,Material C", "9,XS,Material D", 
"9,XXS,Material A", "9,XXS,Material B"), class = "factor"), a = c(281L, 
196L, 59L, 96L, 442L, 98L), b = c(7194L, 4298L, 3457L, 2982L, 
4280L, 3605L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: beta[1,] is the first row.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `beta[1,]` to extract the first row. 
Since you are wanting the first value in `beta$a` and `beta$b` you can use `beta$a[1]` and `beta$b[1]`

```r
SampleValues <- rbeta(10000,beta$a[1],beta$b[1])
ggplot(data.frame(vals=SampleValues))+
  geom_histogram(aes(x=vals))
```